# Find users with best matching ratings

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Can anyone help me create a well performing way of doing the following?:

I have some users rating some different items.

To provide a user with good recommendations I need to find users with similar taste. So that i can recommend high rated items from other users with similar taste.

My data is coming from a database mapped with Entity Framework.

I have a working algorithm but is performing poorly do to way to much looping. Any ideas?

/kent

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const int NoOfUsers = 100;
            const int NoOfRatingsPerUser = 100;
            const int NoOfDifferentItems = 100;

            var listOfRatings = new List<Rating>();

            var r = new Random();

            for (int user = 0; user < NoOfUsers; user++)
            {
                for (int ratingsPerUser = 0; ratingsPerUser < NoOfRatingsPerUser; ratingsPerUser++)
                {
                    var rating = new Rating();
                    rating.Score = r.Next(1, 10);
                    rating.ItemId = r.Next(1, NoOfDifferentItems);
                    rating.UserId = user;
                    listOfRatings.RemoveAll(x => x.UserId == user && x.ItemId == rating.ItemId);
                    listOfRatings.Add(rating);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        struct Rating
        {
            public int ItemId;

            public int Score;

            public int UserId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really a LINQ or EF question. What you need to do is plan (or ask for help with) a matching algorithm. Once you have that algorithm you can ask for help implementing it a specific technology (e.g. LINQ) if you get stuck.

Comment: It seems that the code that you posted doesn't at all correspond to what you are describing in your question. Additionally this code doesn't seem to be doing anything useful at all - can you explain the purpose of it ? And can you post the relevant part here - the one that you want to re-write, preferably with some comments ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a rating algorithm.   You were getting killed on search.  KeyedCollection is a perfect fit here.

62 milliseconds on a P4.  At 1000 (not 100);

```
    public void BuildData()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        RatingKC Ratings = new RatingKC();

        const Int16 NoOfUsers = 1000;
        const Int16 NoOfRatingsPerUser = 1000;
        const Int16 NoOfDifferentItems = 1000;
        Int16 itemID;
        int score;
        Int32 key;
        var r = new Random();

        for (Int16 userID = 0; userID < NoOfUsers; userID++)
        {
            for (int ratingsPerUser = 0; ratingsPerUser < NoOfRatingsPerUser; ratingsPerUser++)
            {
                itemID = (Int16)r.Next(1, NoOfDifferentItems);
                score = r.Next(1, 10);
                key = (userID & 0xffff) + (itemID << 16);
                if (Ratings.Contains(key))
                {
                    Ratings[key].Score = score;
                }
                else
                {
                    Ratings.Add(new Rating(userID, itemID, score));   
                }
            }
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Count = " + Ratings.Count.ToString() + " Time = " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
public class RatingKC : KeyedCollection<int, Rating>
{
    // The parameterless constructor of the base class creates a 
    // KeyedCollection with an internal dictionary. For this code 
    // example, no other constructors are exposed.
    //
    public RatingKC() : base() { }

    // This is the only method that absolutely must be overridden,
    // because without it the KeyedCollection cannot extract the
    // keys from the items. The input parameter type is the 
    // second generic type argument, in this case OrderItem, and 
    // the return value type is the first generic type argument,
    // in this case int.
    //
    protected override int GetKeyForItem(Rating item)
    {
        // In this example, the key is the part number.
        return item.Key;
    }
}
public class Rating: Object
{
    public Int16 UserId { get; private set; }
    public Int16 ItemId { get; private set;}
    public int Score { get; set;}
    public Int32 Key { get { return (UserId & 0xffff) + (ItemId << 16); } }
    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        //Check for null and compare run-time types.
        if (obj == null || !(obj is Rating)) return false;
        Rating item = (Rating)obj;
        return (UserId == item.UserId && ItemId == item.ItemId);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Key;
    }

    public Rating(Int16 userId, Int16 itemId, int score)
    { UserId = userId; ItemId = itemId; Score = score; }
    public Rating(Int16 userId, Int16 itemId)
    { UserId = userId; ItemId = itemId; }
}
```